# Send Base64 Encoded Image From Android to NojeJS with Data Wrapper

Tags: java, android, base64, mime-types

I am using Android InputSteam to get the image data and encode it using Base64 so that it can be send to my NodeJS server, here is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.readFully(inputStream).toByteArray();
String encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

I have been tried to search around but most of the tutorial was only sending the plain Base64 encoded image directly without the data wrapper, I want it to be contain with the MIME type like below so that in NodeJS I can know which image file type is it:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z...
```

But now the output of `encodedBase64` is only:

```
R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z...
```